Sci-Fi movie involving Vat-grown Lifeforms
Trying to identify a movie that was showing on TV around the 1990/2000s. Apologies in advance for the vagueness, I only remember short scenes of the movie.
The plot involved Vats/Tanks with fleshy masses being grown inside - I believe by human scientists. This was done in a Dark Industrial looking complex, with one of the scenes wading through water (flooded chamber?).
The climax may have involved terminating/liquidating/melting various organism tubes and destroying the facility.
I vaguely remember that there may have been a woman formed/contaminated from the vat material and that another character was in a relationship with this woman.
There was a scene involving the removal of an organism/organ from inside a person, during surgery.
It's not Species or Under the Skin. The location was mainly based around the facility, no free roam/escape in the plot.
The genre is Sci-Fi and possibly Horror. Movie was in colour and was in English.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any  names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Alien: Resurrection (1997)


200 years after the conclusion of Alien 3, the Company is able to
  resurrect Ripley through the process of cloning and the scientists
  successfully take the Queen Alien out of her. But, Ripley's DNA gets
  mixed up with the Queen's and she begins to develop certain alien
  characteristics. The scientists begin breeding the aliens, but they
  later escape. Soon the Xeno-morphs are running amok on the ship, which
  is on course to Earth. The Queen then gives birth to a deadly new
  breed of alien, which could spell disaster for the entire human race.
  It's up to Ripley and a band of space pirates to stop the ship before
  it reaches Earth.

Ripley in a vat:

Alien organism is removed:

A still from the scene where they wade through water and eventually fight the aliens submerged:

And here's the scene where she destroys the clone you mention:



An image of the clone-vats she also destroy:

Trailer:




+1 for Quality answer with pictures and extremely tight fitting response, but unfortunately I do remember the vat lifeforms as more formless biomass (not cloned humans and not alien Eggs). Also I believe that I would have been able to recognise Sigourney Weaver or Xenomorphs.

The plot does seem to fit surprisingly well with the information available. I'll keep lokning, good luck dinding it

Thanks, it was very good answer and close fit. Sorry I couldn't be more clear - I remember the vibe more than anything else - felt like a cross between Alien atmosphere and Invisible Man. Quality Answer would give more than +1 if I could.
